# Opening a report with multiple criteria

Tags: vba, ms-access

Can someone please guide me on this? When I use:

```
If Not IsNull(Me.filterLocation) And Not IsNull(Me.filterArea) Then
    If Application.CurrentProject.AllReports("rptFiltered").IsLoaded = 
    False Then
    DoCmd.OpenReport "rptFiltered", acViewPreview, , (("ColumnLocation = 
    '" & Me.filterLocation.Value & "'") And ("ColunmArea = '" & 
    Me.filterArea.Value & "'"))

Exit Sub
End If
```

I get a syntax error with the code above. It works if I remove:

```
And ("ColunmArea = '" & Me.filterArea.Value & "'"))
```

But I also need records with this column values to also show on the report.

Comment: Learn to [debug](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)! Lookup the arguments`Openreport`needs (type).

Comment: After research  I am not sure whats happening that is why I have posted.

Comment: Take the [tour] (what should be first on SO!!) and read [ask], to see what your question is missing and how to improve it!

Comment: 'also to show on report' indicates that you want to show all records with the ColumnArea? Your`And`operator between the two conditions lead to only`ColumnLocation`is shown that matches`ColumnArea`too. If that is not what you want use`Or`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. If a single expression traverses onto a new line, you will need to suffix the preceding line with a line continuation symbol, which, in VBA, is the underscore character (`_`) e.g.:

   ```
   DoCmd.OpenReport "YourReport", _
   acViewNormal
   ```
2. The `and` should be included in the `where` condition:

   ```
   DoCmd.OpenReport "rptFiltered", acViewPreview, , _
   "ColumnLocation = '" & Me.filterLocation.Value & "' AND ColumnArea = '" & Me.filterArea.Value & "'"
   ```

   You can use the syntax highlighting of any code editor to help you to determine the elements of the code which form a string, and which lie outside of the string.
3. You have a typo in the name of one of your fields:

   ```
   ColunmArea
   '   ^---------- I'm guessing this should be ColumnArea
   ```
4. Finally, the parentheses surrounding the `where` condition argument are not recommended (except when you want to [force an argument to be passed by value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-force-an-argument-to-be-passed-by-value)).